# Почему на убунту в юнити Audio Source не видет музыкальные файлы?

Tags: unity3d, ubuntu

Смотрите, у меня ОС Ubuntu, в Unity не видет Audio Source не видет музыкальные файлы, как это решить? Вот ссылка на скрин - https://imgur.com/Hv1SLZ1

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Смотрите, вот у меня проблема в том что в аудио соурс не видит музыкальные файлы, ну вот скриншот - https://imgur.com/7wBKskr, я работаю на убунту и впервые столкнулся с проблемой и не знаю как её решить, если в друх словах то чтобы исправить эту ошибку с музыкальными файлами